# A2Hosting: npm works in terminal, but not for cron worker

Tags: node.js, npm, shared-hosting

I am using A2hosting and trying to configure cron worker, but no luck yet.

I followed this [article](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts) to install node and npm, which is basically list of commands below

```
cd ~
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.9.1/node-v12.9.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar xvf node-v12.9.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
mv node-v12.9.1-linux-x64 nodejs
mkdir ~/bin
cp nodejs/bin/node ~/bin
cd ~/bin
ln -s ../nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js npm
```

I have tried multiple commands

`npm run --prefix ~/cloudflare-upload-tool start`  which produces `/bin/bash: npm: command not found`

and

`~/nodejs/bin/npm run --prefix ~/cloudflare-upload-tool start` which produces  `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

Both commands run fine in terminal, could you tell what are my options to fix this?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cloudflare-upload-tool",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "env-cmd node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "cloudflare": "^2.7.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "form-data": "^3.0.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "tus-js-client": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support told that this approach is not supported. Ended up creating node js app using UI, stopping it as we don't need to expose it and using command for cron worker below as suggested in other [article](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-software/create-application-with-nodejs-selector)

```
source /home/<USERNAME>/nodevenv/cloudflare_upload_tool/10/bin/activate && cd /home/<USERNAME>/cloudflare_upload_tool && npm run start
```

[image: node app]